# Printer cannot get a handle

Tags: java, windows, swt

I'm setting up some tests for my printing module. The test currently looks something like this:

```
    PrinterData pdfPrinter = null;

    for (final PrinterData p : Printer.getPrinterList()) {
        if (p.name.contains("PDF")) {
            pdfPrinter = p;
            break;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull("No PDF printer found!", pdfPrinter);

    pdfPrinter.fileName = Paths.get("target/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".pdf");
    pdfPrinter.printToFile = true;

    Printer printer = new Printer(pdfPrinter);
    // and now do some stuff
```

It works locally started from Eclipse and via Maven / Tycho build.

When started on our build server (Jenkins, but I'm not so sure that's relevant), the following exception gets thrown:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.printing.Printer.create(Printer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.printing.Printer.<init>(Printer.java:203)
```

It doesn't make any sense to me. There are a couple more tests in this reactor, but I believe all of them close their resources correctly. And it would be very weird that just after adding this tests all the handles were depleted.

So there must be a reason why the `Printer` cannot be initialized. What is this reason? How do I fix my code?

**Note:** I have tried different printers, and initializing most brings the above error (maybe related to the headless build?), but some of them work, e.g. "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" and "Fax".

Comment: Do check this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=254566

Comment: @Shashwat That's Mac OS and the exception gets thrown in `Printer.getPrinterList()`. My code gets to the last line (so there ARE printers installed, which isn't surprising since Windows always has the PDF printer).

Comment: SWT uses the 'No more handles' error for all sorts of errors related to handles. So, confusingly, it often doesn't mean you are out of handles. The error thrown at line 269 in Printer.create seems to mean that the Windows `CreateDC` API call failed.

Comment: @greg-449 So... what's a DC and what could have gone wrong when creating it?

Comment: Sorry, but that is all Windows API stuff that I know nothing about